# Arrows between two elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I want an arrow connecting the expanded flex item.( The flex items are expanded to one complete row on clicking them. Please run the code.). The arrow must be a down pointing arrow connecting the last unexpanded element and the expanded element.

```html
  2nd element clicked:
  
  |--------|                       
  |        |-----|                      1st row                 
  |1st ele |     |             
  |--------|     |    
                \/
  |------------------------|
->|                        |-->         2nd row
  |      2nd               |
  |------------------------|
  
  
  |--------|      |--------|                   
->|        |----->|        |----->      3rd row        
  | 3rd    |      | 4th    |                 
  |--------|      |--------|
```

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    $('#Demosss').append($('<li  class="flex-item">').text('abc'))
    $(this).insertAfter($('[class^="flex-item"]').last());
});

$(document).on('click', '.flex-item' ,function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('flexActive')
})
```

```css
.fulex{
  display: flex;
  //white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  //display:none;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  /* Safari */
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
//  width:600px;
}

.flex-item {
  background: green;
  //display:flex;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.flexActive {
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  flex: 1 1;
  margin-right: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.flex-item {
  margin-left: .75em;
}

.flex-item:not(:first-child):before {
  content: '\21E2';
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fulex">

<ul id="Demosss" class="flex-container">

<!-- add LI here -->
</ul>


<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to add a down arrow to the target element you can add css property to the `flexActive`.

Add this to the CSS.

```
.flexActive:after{
    content: '\21E2';
    color:black;
    position:absolute;
    top:-80px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6smLLgyd/)**